# Where are abilities stored in Authorization service for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

The section for the `Authorization` service at the Laravel docs states some examples such as:

```
// Models
if ($request->user()->can('update-post', $post)) {
    // Update Post...
}

// Views
@can('update-post', $post)
    <a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}/edit">Edit Post</a>
@endcan
```

However, there is no mention to any kind of `migration` and `schema`.

How and where are the `abilities` stored?

Comment: The `abilities` are defined in a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#defining-abilities) and/or in [policy classes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#policies). The logic of these functions depends on your requirements.

Comment: Does my answer make sense or would you like more clarification on anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You* define how the authorization rules work. Maybe that will involve database tables or other data, but it will all be customized by you. For instance, check out the ["Defining Abilities" section of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#defining-abilities) to see how you would implement an `update-post` ability.

In your `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    });
}
```

This just checks if the `user_id` on a post is the same as a passed in `user_id`. But this is where you would define your specific logic.

Laracasts has a really great [video series on ACL](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/13) that clears a lot of this up.

Comment: Where are permissions stored?

Comment: You make permissions up yourself and then define them. So for instance, in this case I am creating a permission called 'update-post'. It is just "stored" in the code. It is merely a function that takes a post and a user and checks if the `user_id` of the post is the same as the `id` of the user. You can define these permissions however you want but there is *not* some necessary `permissions` table (unless you set one up yourself and make all of your permissions run from it).

Comment: But that is all Laravel Authorization does - provide you an easy, more clear way of writing functions *that you make up entirely yourself* with rules *that you make up entirely yourself* that relate to permission functionality.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression it would be something like the ACL from Sentry.

Comment: I'm not sure how Sentry handles ACL, but with Laravel this leaves it entirely up to you how to handle permission data. So for simple apps you will just define all of them in the code one-by-one. However, if you wanted to, you *could* create a `permissions` table yourself and have your service provider loop through that table to define rules instead of hardcoding them in. But there is no convention for that or automation from Laravel because it has no way of knowing how you'd define those rules. I'd really suggest watching that video series I linked to.

Comment: Yes, I'll watch the first 2 free videos. Thanks for pointing that out.